# Bayesian Statistics problem- calculating posterior probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, posterior

Given that Hamilton wrote 51 Federalist papers and Madison wrote 14 Federalist papers, there’s a dispute over how to attribute 12 other papers between these two authors. Diving further, in Hamilton’s 51 papers, the word “upon” was used 3.24 times per 1000 words. In Madison’s 14 papers, the word “upon” was used 0.23 times per 1000 words.

So if the word "upon" is used in one of the disputed papers 3 times within 1000 words and assuming that the prior probability that its Hamilton's paper is 51/(14+51), are my calculations correct in determining the posterior probability that the paper is written by Hamilton:

P(Hamilton|upon=3) = P(upon|Hamilton) * P(Hamilton) / P(upon=3) = (3.24/1000)*(51/(14+51))/(3/1000)= 0.85

I feel as though my logic is wrong since I am just beginning to learn Bayesian statistics. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The information here is the word "upon" appearing three times per 1K in your paper, but you use it as a probability in the denominator. That'd be certainly false. Although the question seems to be lacking something/needs assumptions that I don't feel very comfortable with, here's how I'd solve it:

Let $H$ be Hamilton, and $M=H'$ be Madison writing the paper, where $P(H)=51/65$. From the explanation we can deduce the probability of appearance of a single word "upon" as: $P(\text{"upon" appears once}|H)=3.24/1000$, and $P(\text{"upon" appears once}|H')=0.23/1000$.

The posterior probability we seek for is $P(H|3 \text{"upon"s appear})$, which can be written as $$P(H|3 \text{"upon"s appear})=\frac{P(3 \text{"upon"s appear|H)}P(H)}{P(3 \text{"upon"s appear|H)}P(H)+P(3 \text{"upon"s appear|H')}P(H')}$$

When substituted $P(3 \text{"upon"s appear|H)}=(3.24/1000)^{3}$ and $P(3 \text{"upon"s appear|H')}=(0.23/1000)^3$, you get the posterior probability.